# rendering a form through jquery in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

i have this application where in i have tasks and subtasks.Every task has a add subtask button,which on clicking goes to jquery script placed in application.html.erb file.which then appends a p tag to hold my new subtask.Now what is want is instead of that paragraph,i want it to display a small subtask creation form consiting of only the :name text field and a save button,which will take it the create action of my subtask controller.

Remember every subtask belongs to a task

this is how i create subtasks now

```
<% provide(:title,'ToDoProject') %>
<% flash.each do |key,value| %>
<div class="alert alert-<%=key %>"><%=value %></div>
<%end%>
<h1>Create a subtask</h1>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span7">
    <%=form_for [@task,@subtask] do |s| %>

    <%=s.label :name %>
    <%=s.text_field :name,autofocus:'true' %>
    <%=s.submit "Save",class:'btn btn-success'%>
    <%end%>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want this same form,but to be get displayed dynamically when a user clicks on add new subtask of my task,so that the user can put a name to the subtask,then click on save and it will get saved to my database.

But all this is required through jquery and using its append function.

here is the new updated show.html.erb with the subtask form and add card button that makes it visible

```
<div class="subtaskform" id="subtask_form_<%=task.id %>" style="width:218px;margin:0 2px 0px 3px;">

                <%= form_for([task, task.subtasks.build]) do |f| %>

                        <%= f.text_area :name,rows:'3',cols:'3'%>


                <%= f.submit "save",class:'btn btn-success' %>
                <a data-id='<%=task.id %>' href="#"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>

                <% end %>

                </div>



                <p class="addcard" id="addcard_<%=task.id%>"><a href="#" data-id='<%= task.id %>' id='add_card_<%= task.id %>'>Add a card...</a></p>
```

here is the jquery code

```
 $('.addcard > a').click(function(e){

          $('#subtask_form_' + $(this).data('id')).show(1000);

e.preventDefault();
   });

          $('.subtaskform a').click(function(e){
           $('#subtask_form_' + $(this).data('id')).hide(1000);
          e.preventDefault();
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) I think

---

**Process**

Basically, you're trying to do something like [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) - loading dynamic data from your Rails server

The problem is you can't load data dynamically from Rails without having an intermediary technology to send [asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

In simple terms, your client-side is HTML & JS, and one of those needs to send a request to your Rails server, rendering the response in your view

---

**Code**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tasks do
    resources :subtasks #creates /tasks/1/subtasks/new etc
end

#app/views/tasks/index.html.erb
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <%= task.name %>
    <%= button_to "New Subtask", new_tasks_subtasks_path(task.id), remote: :true %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/subtasks_controller.rb
respond_to :html, :js

def new
    @task = params[:task_id]
    @subtask = SubTask.new
end

def create
    @subtask = Subtask.new(subtask_params)
    @subtask.save
end

private
def subtask_params
   params.require(:subtask).permit(:name, :etc)
end

#app/views/subtasks/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@task,@subtask] do |s| %>
    <%=s.label :name %>
    <%=s.text_field :name,autofocus:'true' %>
    <%=s.submit "Save",class:'btn btn-success'%>
<% end %>

#app/views/subtasks/new.js.erb
$(".parent_div").append("<%=j render "new", layout: false %>")
```

Comment: thank you fr your reply Rich peck,but i figured out another way of doing it,what i am doin right now is that i have my form of creating subtask hidden,and when a user click on add subtask,its visibility changes using jquery.Everything is working fine i am able to save the subtasks as well.Now i am searching for how to refresh the content of my div task once the new subtask is added.I think i l require ajax for that.Was just googling about that only now

Comment: No problem! If you need any further help, please just let me know :)

Comment: it seems that ajax is going over my head.do u have ny simple ajax script that will work for me

Comment: What do you need it to do?

Comment: c now i hav this add_card button which makes the form for a new sub task creation visible.so now i can write anything in that form for my new subtask and click on save button and it saves my subtask.i just want it to reflect that new saved subtask inside the task div.without me having to refresh the page,now i nee dto refresh but i dont want that and i read that its only possible through ajax

Comment: You can use an altered version of the answer I provided - would you like me to adapt it for you?

Comment: i have added my new updated code,pls have a look at it and if u can provide an ajax script for wat i need according to my code,that wuld be great.

Comment: Rich peck,u can have a look at my attempt toward achieving this through ajax.I have posted that question over here with all the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073248/refreshing-a-div-with-ajax-in-rails

Comment: Sure, let me take a look!