# refreshing a div with ajax in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a todo kind of app,where in their are div tasks which have p id="task_"+<%=task.id%>
subtasks.I have a form for creating a new subtask at every show page of my project.

To understand this here is the code that i am using

Its the show.html.erb of project

```
<% provide(:title,'ToDoProject') %>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="user span9 default-skin">
        <ul class="myul">
            <% if @project.tasks.any? %>
            <%=render :partial=> @project %>
            <%end%>

        </ul>   
    </div>

    <div class="span3" id="rightcolumn">
        <p><%=@project.name %></p>
        <p><%=link_to 'Add Task',new_project_task_path(@project) %></p>

    </div>

</div>
```

here is the partial project

```
<% project.tasks.each do |task| %>
<%=render :partial=>task %>

<%end%>
```

Then their is partial for task

```
   <div class="span5 tasks" id='tasks_<%=task.id %>'>
    <div class="addtaskdiv" id="addtaskdiv_<%=task.id %>">
        <p><b><%=task.taskname %></b>
        <%=link_to 'edit name',edit_task_path(task) %></p>  
        <% task.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>

            <%=render :partial=>subtask %>
            <!--
                <p class="subtask" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><%=subtask.name %>
                <a data-id='<%=subtask.id %>' href="#" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a></p-->
        <%end%>

        <%=render 'layouts/modal' %>
    </div>
    <div class="subtaskform" id="subtask_form_<%=task.id %>" style="width:218px;margin:0 2px 0px 3px;">

        <%= form_for [task, task.subtasks.build],:remote => true do |f| %>

            <%= f.text_area :name,rows:'3',cols:'3'%>

            <%= f.submit "save",class:'btn btn-success' %>
            <a data-id='<%=task.id %>' href="#"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>

        <% end %>

    </div>



    <p class="addcard" id="addcard_<%=task.id%>"><a href="#" data-id='<%= task.id %>' id='add_card_<%= task.id %>'>Add a card...</a></p>
</div>
```

Finally here is the partial for subtask

```
     <div class="dropdown">
                <a data-id='<%=subtask.id %>' href="#" style="float:right;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="margin-right:10px;margin-top:10px;"></i></a>
                <p class="subtask" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><%=subtask.name %></p>


                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is my subtask controller create method

```
         def create
    @task=Task.find(params[:task_id])
    @project=@task.project
    @subtask=@task.subtasks.create(params[:subtask])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @subtask.save
            format.html{redirect_to @project}
            format.js

            flash[:success]="Task created successfully"
        else
            render new
        end
    end
end
```

and here is the create.js.erb file for the ajax call

```
       $('#adddtaskdiv_'+ <%=@task.id %>).append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial=>@subtask) %>');
```

I want that when i create a subtask it should get rendered without refreshing my page.But somehow its not working here.I saw the log it looks correct,but nothing on the browser seems to be working.

Here is the image of the console log of rails after i click on save of subtasks
[image]

This is how the ui looks now

[image]

Comment: You mention it looks okay in the log - is this the Rails log or the Javascript console log?

Comment: its the rails log,i think the issue liew somewhere in rendering the subtask by ajax

Comment: may b i am rendering the subtask incorrectly,der r so many task and subtasks,its getting a lil confusing at the moment

Comment: Rich peck,pls have a look at the console image that i have added.u might figure out the problem from der

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a set of issues here:

1. Which URL is your Ajax pinging?
2. Is your `create` method actually creating a record?
3. Is `create.js.erb` loading?

---

**Ajax**

Here's the low-down on Ajax -

Rails works via [HTTP "requests"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). Every time you send a "request" to your application, it returns data corresponding to the data in that request

This means if you want to append new data to your page (without refreshing), you need to send a request somehow (Ajax)

Ajax is basically Javascript acting like a pseudo-browser; sending a request to the server on your behalf (asynchronously), allowing you to call back data & append it to the DOM

**URL**

```
    <%= form_for [task, task.subtasks.build],:remote => true do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_area :name,rows:'3',cols:'3'%>

        <%= f.submit "save",class:'btn btn-success' %>
        <a data-id='<%=task.id %>' href="#"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>

    <% end %>
```

You're using [Rails build-in Ajax](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax), but we need to know which route it will be pinging. You need to show us which URL the Ajax is sending data to. I think part of your issue *may* be with the `task.subtasks.build` call

---

**Create**

Your `create` method can be refactored a little:

```
#app/controllers/subtasks_controller.rb
def create
    @task= Task.find(params[:task_id])
    @project = @task.project

    @subtask = @task.subtasks.new(subtask_params)
    @subtask.save

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html{redirect_to @project, flash[:success] = "Task created successfully"}
       format.js # -> you can't send the Flash object through xhr
    end
end 

private
def subtask_params
    params.require(:subtask).permit(:name)
end

#app/models/subtask.rb
Class SubTask < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true # -> Causes forms to fail gracefully
end
```

---

**Create JS**

If your `create` method is working, the problem may lie with your JS:

```
#app/views/subtasks/create.js.erb
$('#addtaskdiv_'+ <%=@task.id %>).append('<%=j render partial: "subtasks/partial_name", object: @subtask %>');
```

Part of the issue is you're sending the `@subtask` instance variable to a partial. I don't think you can do that (might be wrong). You need to call an absolute path for the partial, and [pass the instance var as an object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: Rich peck wer u able to figure out the problem.i have added the log pic

Comment: Rich peck ur code worked for me.Thanks again.U r genius my friend.

Comment: Hey thanks bud! I actually forgot to respond :( I hope it still works for you, and if you need any more help, please just comment!

Comment: Rich Peck,since now you are completely aware of what the application is.I have this minor css issue.Since i have many diff projects and they all will have varying no of tasks.So how can i manage the width of the task div.Currently i have set it to 3000px.But since diff projects might require less width or more width may be.So how to handle that.

Comment: Can't you set the width dynamically? No-one uses a 3000px monitor currently, so that seems outlandish to me? Why not just set `display: block` and/or `width: 100%`?

Comment: i am using a scroll bar,so the width of 3000px is inside a scroll bar.What i am doing now is that i am using jquery to calculate the width based on the no of task a project has.So that does the work for me

Comment: this is what i am doing now <script>
$('.myul').width(<%=project.tasks.count %>*232+900);
</script>

Comment: this solved the problem for me.But i need your feedback on it.What do u think is it Bad programming.

Comment: Yes I think it's bad programming, because JS is not meant as a styling system :) Do you have a live link for your page? I'll see if I can suggest anything more specific for you!

Comment: live link is nt der yet.I can send u a snapshot of how it looks now.

Comment: Hav a look at the ui dat i av posted.This is how i want it to work

Comment: I believe you could use CSS. [I tried to do it](http://jsfiddle.net/Na44X/), but you need to use a fixed width for the container. So I suppose setting that width with JS will be the best option?

Comment: Alright,so i am keeping as it is for the time being.Once the site is ready and live,i will show it you.If their are any improvements which i am sure will be their,U will be in a better position to suggest.

Comment: Rich peck,i have added authentication functionality into the app now,and now only the current_user can create projects.So now what i am doing is that a project is created using current_user.projects.new and current_user.projects.create.The authentication is authlogic.What trouble i have got now is that on creating a project,the production,development and testing task are created properly,but its also creating a blank task for me.i dont know,y dats happenin.Can u pls have a look into this issue

Comment: I'll have a look in a minute if that's okay!

Comment: to give u some info abt what is happenin is,if i keep after_create filter in project.rb,then that empty task is created first,and for before_create filter,it creates that empty task at the end.So something in the controller may b causing this trouble

Comment: i think i have understood where the problem is.Basically the task table was our join table.So i added a new user_id column to it so that it acts as join table for my users and project as well.Now what happens is that since that task table has task_name column as well,and when i create a project associated with the user.it updates the join table with the task_id and project_id and empty task_name,may b this is the problem

Comment: Rich peck,wat to do to tackle this issue.

Comment: Rich peck,do u have some time to look into a small js issue that i am getting.I l post the question once i get ur reply,so that we can communicate when ur online.

Comment: Sure, send the question link & I'll hvae a look!

Comment: here is the link for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645237/error-in-ajax-rendering-of-the-bootstrap-dropdown-in-rails3

Comment: Thanks buddy - let me have a look