# error in ajax rendering of the bootstrap dropdown in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails app which is todo kind of app.So it has projects,projects then have tasks like 1st task,2nd task and 3rd task,then each of those tasks have subtasks.

Now each of those subtasks have a bootstrap modal associated with them and a dropdown with them.

Now the problem that i am facing right now is that,when i create a subtask using ajax request,it creates the new subtask without refreshing the page,so thats working fine,it even creates a new modal associated with that new subtask.So till here all is good,but the new dropdown for this new subtask is not getting created.

I dont understnd why is this happeing,if the new modal can get created on ajax refresh,y is the new dropdown not getting rendered,coz both the modal and the dropdown code are in the same partial.

Here are the codes that i have written

Here is the task partial,in tasks/_task.html.erb

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5  tasks" id='tasks_<%=task.id %>'>
 <div class="addtaskdiv" id="addtaskdiv_<%=task.id %>">

<p><b>

    <%=task.taskname %>
</b>


<span style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><%=link_to '',edit_task_path(task),class:'fa fa-pencil-square-o' %></span>
</p>
<div class="addtaskmovable">
    <% task.subtasks.each do |subtask| %>
        <%=render :partial=>subtask%>


        <%end%>
</div>//end of addtaskmovable




</div>//end of addtaskdiv
<div class="subtaskform" id="subtask_form_<%=task.id %>" style="width:218px;margin:0 2px 0px 3px;">

    <%= form_for [task, task.subtasks.build],:remote => true,:html => {
                        :id => task.id, :class => 'elm_class'
                         } do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_area :name,rows:'3',cols:'3',:class=>'myarea'%>

        <%= f.submit "save",class:'btn btn-mini btn-success col-md-4' %>
        <a data-id='<%=task.id %>' href="#"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" style="margin:10px auto;"></i></a>

    <% end %>

    </div>//end of subtaskform

    <p class="addcard" id="addcard_<%=task.id%>"><a href="#" data-id='<%= task.id %>' id='add_card_<%= task.id %>'>Add a card...</a></p>
</div>//end of task div
```

Now here is the subtask partial in subtasks/_subtask.html.erb

```
<%=render 'layouts/modal',:subtask=>subtask %>


<div class="dropdown" id="dropdownmenu<%=subtask.id %>"> 


<a data-id='<%=subtask.id %>' data-target="#" style="float:right;" class="dropdown-toggle" id='dropdownMenu<%=subtask.id %>' data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" style="margin-right:10px;margin-top:10px;"></i></a>
<p class="subtask" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_<%=subtask.id %>"> 
<%=subtask.name %>
</p>


<%=render 'subtasks/dropdown',:subtask=>subtask %>
</div>
```

And finally here is the dropdown code,which is not getting rendered properly

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown<%=subtask.id %>" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu<%=subtask.id %>">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Note:The dropdown was getting rendered properly on ajax request in bootstrap2,but when i switched to bootstrap3,it stopped working.

And finally here is the ajax code create.js.erb

```
 $('#addtaskdiv_'+ <%=@task.id %>).append('<%=j render partial: "subtasks/subtask", object: @subtask %>');
 $(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");
 $('#subtask_form_'+<%=@task.id %>).hide(1000);
```

And finally here is my application.html.erb file which has all the js in it

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title><%=yield(:title) %></title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/pic2.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "jquery.custom-scrollbar", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "modernizr.custom.28468.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.cslider.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.custom-scrollbar" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.custom-scrollbar.min" %>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "style", :media => "all" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "style1", :media => "all" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "fontello", :media => "all" %>



   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".myultask" ).sortable();
$( ".myultask" ).disableSelection();
$( ".addtaskmovable" ).sortable();
$( ".addtaskmovable" ).disableSelection();

  $('.dropdown > a').click(function(e){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  $(".user").customScrollbar({
    updateOnWindowResize: true
  });
  $("#subtask").click(function(){
   $('#myModal').modal();
  });
  $('.nav li').click(function(event){
    //remove all pre-existing active classes
    $('.active').removeClass('active');

    //add the active class to the link we clicked
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
        $('.addcard > a').click(function(e){

          $('#subtask_form_' + $(this).data('id')).show(1000);




   e.preventDefault(); 

 });
        $('.subtaskform a').click(function(e){
          $('#subtask_form_' + $(this).data('id')).hide(1000);
          e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('.addtask > a').click(function(e){
          $('.addtaskform').show(1000);

          e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#close').click(function(e){
          $('.addtaskform').hide(1000);
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.addproject > a').click(function(e){
          $('.addprojectform').show(1000);

          e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#close').click(function(e){
          $('.addprojectform').hide(1000);
          e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('.mydes > a').click(function(e){
          $('#subtaskdesform_' + $(this).data('id')).show(1000);
          e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('.myclose').click(function(e){
          $(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");

          $('#subtaskdesform_'+ $(this).data('id')).hide(1000);
          e.preventDefault();
        });
         $('#da-slider').cslider({
      autoplay  : true,
      bgincrement : 450
    });



});
</script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <%=render 'layouts/header' %>


 <%= yield %>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Their is a miner add to it,i think its some kind of js issue,coz when i moved the js for the dropdown right at the top of js inside the <script> tags,it started working but very slow it is working.i have to click thrice or four times to get the dropdown.so may b its a js issue

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to define the cause of the issue:

> ```
> when I switched to Bootstrap 3 ,it stopped working
> ```

The issue will either be with the element ID, or the javascript element identifier not picking up the dropdown

Have you got any errors in your javascript console? Obviously your other code is running, so the JS request is valid; meaning there'll be something wrong with the dropdown code, or how it's being applied to the page

---

**Errors**

You've put up too much code to make an educated guess on what the issue is. It would be best if you let us know which errors you're seeing in your brwoser console

Comment: the subtask has an icon on which when u click,u get the dropdown,but it aint creating a dropdown for the newly created subtask.the same problem is with the tasks as well,when a new task gets created with ajax,the option to add a subtask to it is nt getting created

Comment: I think its some kind of js issue only,but cant figure out where is the problem.cant switch back to bootstrap2 also,so stuck here

Comment: Rich peck,found the solution finally.It was coz bootstrap.js was getting loaded twice,nd coz of that it was creating a problem for me.nyways thanks for ur comment.U r reply to my msg itself solves the problem.Thanks dude.